# Spacelike, timelike, lightlike vectors and the light-cone structure

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors, causality

Consider a semi-Riemannian manifold which of these statements is false:

- All vectors on the light-cone are light-like, all vectors in the interior of the light-cone are time-like and all vectors in the exterior of the light-cone are space-like.
- All space-like vectors lie in the exterior of the light-cone, all time-like vectors lie in the interior of light-cone, and all light-like vectors lie on the light-cone.

I can't see which statements are false, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this Homework?

Comment: @mmeent, No it's a part of lecture notes, to check if you understand an idea. In this case being the definition of the light cone, interior, and exterior of it.

Comment: Which lecture notes? Which page?

Comment: @Joel If you tell us why you cant see which statement is false or show us your thinking process we can help you in a better way

Comment: @Reign I can see that the first pullet point might to be true from the definition of the light-cone, interior and exterior of it. but what i can't see is why the second one might be false.

Comment: @Qmechanic The lecture notes are not made public, but i can post a snapshot of the definitions if that's OK.

Comment: A snapshot isn't helpful (& we generally frown on images of text on Stack Exchange). But we do like people to give a proper reference to the source document when they copy offsite material here.

Comment: The definitions I am referring to are given here [link](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~aretakis/columbiaGR.pdf) in section 1.3.1 Causality Theory, is this helpful and acceptable?

Comment: @Joel Cant both be true ?

Comment: very nice link (+1)! About your question...as @Reign says: can't both be true?

Comment: @Reign Yes, but in the course I am attending for some reason we are using the convention which is that the zero vector is space-like, I was not aware of this until  recently. And I can't see a reason for this convention!

Comment: @Joel That is odd.  I never heard that convention as well. Have you ever talked about it with your teacher ?

Comment: @Reign Yes indeed it is, I asked and one of the reasons is that we do not want Riemannian manifolds to have time-like or null vectors, and she said that other reasons will become more apparent as we progress in the course.

Comment: @Joel I am not an expert but it seems that in Riemannian geometry the inner product must be positive definite, as your teacher claimed. But in Semi(Pseudo) Riemannian geometry inner product can be positive, negative or zero. Maybe you can try mathstack for more information.

Comment: @Joel   [1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Definition
  [2]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Definition

Comment: @Reign I will check that out, Thanks.